# Making a function mandatory in an extended class, possible?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax

In Java, is it possible to define a function/method which **must** be overridden in order to be valid?

For example, say I have a drawable object with `draw` and `update` functions. I want a way to automatically make users of the class acknowledge that those functions need to defined, or they will do nothing.

Also, I wonder if Eclipse (or Eclipse ADT in my case) can automatically populate these required functions automatically upon extension.

It seems like a very simple question, but Googling and Stack searches prove useless. Thank you for any assistance

Comment: use an interface maybe?

Comment: It's almost what I want, but an interface cannot function on it's own. I don't want to pester users to include an interface just to make the code more strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about an **abstract method**:

```
public abstract returnType methodName(/*...args...*/);
```

To do that, you also have to mark your class `abstract`:

```
public abstract YourClass {
    // ...
}
```

Alternately, you could define the method in an interface, have your class `implement` the interface without actually defining the method(s) it contains, and declare the class `abstract`:

```
public abstract class YourClass implements TheInterface {
    // ...
}
```

> Also, I wonder if Eclipse (or Eclipse ADT in my case) can automatically populate these required functions automatically upon extension.

Yes, Eclipse has a feature to do that. I no longer use Eclipse so I don't recall the specifics, but it's definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Use an interface

and/or

- Declare your class `abstract` and create an abstract method

Also, take a look at the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: Thanks @antonio. Correct answer, but T.J. Crowder got in first and continued to elaborate on his answer after his initial submission

Comment: @1owk3y undoubtedly, that's why I upvoted his answer :)

Comment: Some feedback too, the dotpoints make it seem as though both 'steps' are necessary, when in reality its a 'one-or-the-other' kind of deal. I feel like it should have been prefaced with 'try one of the following', or the first dotpoint could have had an 'or' at the end. Thanks again!

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer so following readers are not confused, thank you for pointing it out!. I added and/or because the options are not exclusive (you can both create an interface and declare your class abstract implementing that interface).